# How to cover holes with disks of a fixed radius?

Tags: algorithms, trees, computational-geometry

So you have a sheet / area of a given dimension, and within this area are holes (their center point(x,y) and radius are given). The problem is you need to cover these holes with patches. These circular patches have a fixed radius (ie: radius of 5) and are not allowed to overlap with each other (but can touch). You're allowed to use as many as you like, the goal is not to find the most optimal number, but to see if it's possible to cover every single hole.

I've solved a similar problem with a KD tree, but due to the 3D dimensional nature of the holes in this problem, I'm unsure on how to approach it. Just looking for a pointer in the right direction, not the coded solution :)

Comment: 3D nature? Is the radius the third "dimension"?

Comment: 3D might be the wrong word, but because the holes aren't simply "points" (they're circles that vary in size, so they have not only a x,y center, but a radius too), I'm unsure how you would sort them if you were to use a KD tree. I've only ever used a KD tree for standard 2D points (x,y)

Comment: Would you mind adding a sketch of your algorithm for points?

Comment: I guess the radius of the hole is smaller than the one of the patches (just to be sure)?

Comment: One simple observation: If every hole has strictly positive diameter, then no solution can involve a patch *partially* overlapping a hole, since in that case the part of the hole that is not covered by that patch must be covered by at least 1 other patch, and on either side of the point where it touches the first patch is a wedge-shaped area of the hole that is too narrow to be covered by any patch.

Comment: Another one: Any subset of holes which can together be covered by a single patch, and for which the minimum distance from any point on a hole inside the subset to a point on a hole outside the subset is > 5, can be safely covered that way (i.e., there is a complete solution that contains that patch).  A necessary condition for a subset to be coverable by a single patch is that every pair of holes $i, j$ in the subset obeys $d(c_i, c_j) + (r_i + r_j)/2 \le 5$, but I'm not sure if this is also sufficient.

Comment: It's *not* sufficient unfortunately: 3 holes of radius 1.25 at the vertices of an equilateral triangle with edge length 5 satisfy the inequality, but can't be covered by a single patch.  Also please ignore the division by 2 in the formula: I was thinking of diameters, not radii.

Comment: Have you [cross-posted this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56054781/573420) with a different account?

Comment: @PeterTaylor No, it is the same account with a different name on SO. I'm closing this question here, as there has been more response on SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been crossposted on SO.